# Setting up OpenGL ES 1.0 in Eclipse on Linux (Ubuntu 3.0.0) for Android development

Tags: java, android, linux, eclipse, opengl-es

I've been developing an Android app in Eclipse (java) using openGL ES 1.0 on a Mac. I had to switch from developing this app on a Mac and continue this project on a laptop running Ubuntu 3.0.0.

The laptop is pretty much a clean slate. I've installed the newest Eclipse and android SDK but when I tried to import the project I had been developing on the mac, I'm seeing errors with locating opengl libraries. From what I've gathered in research, it looks like I may need a wrapper or emulator (Mesa3d? ARM?). I'm not using the Eclipse android simulator but rather using it as an IDE, debugger, and to install my app on a HTC Desire.

I'm fairly new to Linux and android app development in general. Does anyone know how to go about installing what's needed to continue to use OpenGL ES 1.0 in Eclipse on Ubuntu 3.0.0.

EDIT: Solved

The OpenGL ES 1.0 libraries are indeed included after installed the android SDK and ADT. I had thought that they weren't as after I moved my project over to my Ubuntu machine, I had errors on my openGL ES functions all of which were "(func) must override a superclass method". Looked again and noticed these were all functions of an "implements (class)" not an "extends (class)"

Supposedly, an error should be thrown by the compiler "if a method annotated with @Override does not actually override a method in a superclass." However, when developing this project in Eclipse on the Mac, it appears that these misplaced @Override annotations were ignored instead of shown as error. A dumb mistake in part on copying snippets of code from tutorials and in part on jumping to a false conclusion about the openGL ES errors.

Comment: Are you using Java or C for the OpenGL part?

Comment: The entire project (including the OpenGL use) is in java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OpenGL ES 1.0 already exists in the Android, although if you are porting it from Java SE the method signatures may be different.

See the following for details:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/opengl.html

Alternatively, it may be additional libraries which you are having problems with. If you have the source to them you can port them, otherwise you'll need to find/make the appropriate Android API equivalents.

Comment: This indeed helped as it pointed me to my source of error. The OpenGL ES 1.0 libraries are indeed included after installed the android SDK and ADT. I had thought that they weren't as after I moved my project over to my Ubuntu machine, I had errors on my openGL ES functions all of which were "(func) must override a superclass method". Looked again and noticed these were all functions of an "implements (class)" not an "extends (class)".